# Show that the function in the Fourier series of a periodic function of period $2L$ are orthogonals

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Show that the function in the Fourier series of a periodic function of period $2L$ are periodic of period $2L$ and orthogonals.

My question is about orthogonality.

$$f(x) = \frac{a_{0}}{2} + \sum_{1}^{\infty}\left(\underbrace{a_{n}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)}_{g(x)} + \underbrace{b_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)}_{h(x)}\right).$$

So, we need to show that

$$\int_{-L}^{L}g(x)\cdot h(x)\mathrm{d}x = 0.$$

But $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ depends implicitly of $f(x)$. How to prove without know $f(x)$? Probably, I think wrong. Maybe I must to prove that

$$\int_{-L}^{L}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\mathrm{d}x = 0,$$
and this is obvious. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have

$$ \int_{-L}^{L} \cos(\frac{n \pi x}{L}) \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L}) dx = 0 \tag{1}$$

now we use the following trigonometric identity

$$ \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\sin(\alpha-\beta)}{2} \tag{2} $$

which turns the integrand into

$$ \cos(\frac{n \pi x}{L}) \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L}) = \frac{\sin(\frac{2 \pi n x}{L}) +\sin(0 )}{2} = \frac{\sin(\frac{2 \pi n x}{L}) }{2}  \tag{3} $$

so our integral becomes

$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{-L}^{L} \sin(\frac{2 \pi n x}{L}) dx = \frac{-L\cos(\frac{2\pi nx}{L})}{4 \pi n}\Big|_{-L}^{L} \tag{4}$$

so we get

$$ \frac{-L}{4\pi n }  \bigg( \cos(\frac{2\pi nL}{L}) - \cos(\frac{-2\pi nL}{L})  \bigg) \tag{5}$$

$$ \frac{-L}{4\pi n }  \bigg( \cos(2n\pi) - \cos(-2n \pi)  \bigg)  = 0 \tag{6}$$

You only need $f(x)$ to get the coefficients.